# Python Loop: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

For a current research project, I am planning to read the JSON object "Main_Text" within a pre-defined time range on basis of Python/Pandas. When running the word-counting loop, the code however yields the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers` for `line = row['Text Main']`.

`Text Main` only contains strings/text and no integers. I have alreay been through trouble-shooting threads but not found a solution to this problem yet. Is there any helpful tweak to make this work?

The JSON file has the following structure:

```
[
{"No":"121","Stock Symbol":"A","Date":"05/11/2017","Text Main":"Sample text"}
]
```

And the relevant code excerpt looks like this:

```
import string
import json
import csv

import pandas as pd
import datetime

import numpy as np


# Loading and reading dataset
file = open("Glassdoor_A.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])


# Create an empty dictionary
d = dict()


# Filtering by date
start_date = "01/01/2009"
end_date = "01/01/2015"

after_start_date = df["Date"] >= start_date
before_end_date = df["Date"] <= end_date

between_two_dates = after_start_date & before_end_date
filtered_dates = df.loc[between_two_dates]

print(filtered_dates)


# Processing
for row in filtered_dates:
    line = row['Text Main']
```

Comment: whats the output of `print(filtered_dates)` because it looks like `row` is a string

Comment: you may iterate over filtered_dates by filtered_dates.iterrows(). Now row is a tuple and you can access elemens by location like row[0] or row[1]

Comment: It yields a summary of the JSON file for rows within the time frame. Hope that helps clarifying your point.

Comment: Thanks, you mean iterate as a replacement for `for row in filtered_dates:` in that case?

Comment: @M.S. yes . that is an option

Comment: I would need a consideration of the full text/string though, rather than an access by rows... is there any way to have this included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filtered_dates` will return an iterator on the column names which are strings. If you want to iterate over the rows you should use iterrows().

Something like that should work :

```
import string
import json
import csv

import pandas as pd
import datetime

import numpy as np


# Loading and reading dataset
file = open("Glassdoor_A.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])


# Create an empty dictionary
d = dict()


# Filtering by date
start_date = "01/01/2009"
end_date = "01/01/2015"

after_start_date = df["Date"] >= start_date
before_end_date = df["Date"] <= end_date

between_two_dates = after_start_date & before_end_date
filtered_dates = df.loc[between_two_dates]

# Processing
for index, row in filtered_dates.iterrows():
    line = row['Text Main']
```